# how to fetch data from database?

Tags: sql-server, silverlight

how we can fetch the data from the database through Silver light? I want the basics only. because i am a fresher in silver light.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends a little on the version of Silverlight that you are using. In any case, there are some very good and comprehensive tutorials out there on the web. Here are a few that will be of interest:

http://silverlight.net/learn/tutorials/sqldatagrid.aspx

http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/data-and-silverlight-2-data-binding/

Answer (score 2):

Expose your data through a WCF service.

Have a look at this tutorial: [Displaying SQL Database Data in a DataGrid using LINQ and WCF](http://silverlight.net/learn/tutorials/sqldatagrid.aspx).

Also:

- [Service-Driven Apps With Silverlight 2 And WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc794260.aspx)
- Brad Abrams's [Business Apps Example for Silverlight 3 RTM and .NET RIA Services](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2009/07/17/business-apps-example-for-silverlight-3-rtm-and-net-ria-services-july-update-part-8-wcf-based-data-source.aspx)
- [.NET RIA Services / WCF Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945123/net-ria-services-wcf-services)