# Is it possible to use RIA Services and EntityFramework.Migrations together in a project?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, wcf-ria-services, ria

On NuGet there are packages:

EntityFramework.Migrations 
EF 4.3.1
EF 4.1
RIA Services, which depends on EF < 4.2.

EntityFramework.Migrations doesn't work, because it is now included in EF 4.3+

I'm using Code First approach, so I need the DbDomainService<> class, which is not available, when RIA Services aren't installed.

Are there any standalone downloads for the above to manually reference in my project?

**EDIT**:

I removed RIA from NuGet packages, updgraded EF to 4.3.1 and then referenced RIA EntityFramework lib from toolkit manually as suggested here: [Can I use RIA Services with Entity Framework 4.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9302931/can-i-use-ria-services-with-entity-framework-4-3)

Unfortuately now I'm getting the following error:

```
The following exception occurred creating the MEF composition container:
Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
The default code generator will be used.
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your problem is related to the T4 code generator of Ria Services. 
You can however get an idea of the type it can't load attaching your debugger (if you use VS don't forget to "Break on ALL Thrown CLR Exception) to the compilation of client side assembly (msbuild MyClientProjectThatContainTheProxy.csproj. )
However, if you just want to "try something", put this

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="4.3.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

in your web.config, to tell the CLR how to resolve depndencies.
More info here: http://mcasamento.blogspot.it/2012/10/entity-framework-5-code-first-and-wcf.html