# Adding a Silverlight UI to normal .NET program?

Tags: .net, silverlight

**The Situation:**

I have a software project written in .NET 4.0 with a WinForms UI. I would like to replace the UI with a Silverlight UI.

The application should work across the web. The reason for using Silverlight and not WPF is platform independence, so the UI might be running on a different OS eventually.

Example: the .NET program produces some data, I would like to plot the data in a Silverlight control.

**The Problem:**

My .NET project uses libraries that are incompatible with Silverlight. Rewriting the entire .NET code in Silverlight would take a very long time.

**The Question:**

What would be a good way to combine the .NET part with the Silverlight part?

Should I add some middle layer to have the two programs communicate with each other, and if yes, what should I use? (I have never done this kind of thing before)

Is there a way to directly call a Silverlight function from a .NET class, e.g. `SLGUI.display_data(dotNET_data)`, or the other way round?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do something like this, is to refactor your code to create a web service and call these from the SL App.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What is the difference between a webservice and a WCF RIA service?  I am somewhat confused by all the different terms I have come across while looking around for answers. WCF, RIA, Entity Framework, ASP.NET, LINQ, ...

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/q/2523629/394381 to understand the difference between Web services and WCF RIA. BTW Entity Framework = ORM, LINQ = "Dont worry to much about this", WCF = new way to do web services and ASP.NET = to build websites in suported .NET languages.

Comment: Thanks. I just followed [Deborah Kurata's tutorial on Silverlight and RIA](http://msmvps.com/blogs/deborahk/archive/2009/11/05/silverlight-ria-services-and-your-business-objects.aspx) to send some data from the .Net to the Silverlight part.

Comment: Your welcome, can you click on the tick to accept this answer.

Comment: this is the best option you have considering the effort and time that will be used compared against porting the non-SL stuff into SL.

Comment: Bahamut, do you mean WCF RIA or webservices?